# Problems with getting reading a value of a range to work correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on an onEdit event that would detect changes made in specific columns. I want to then send an email notification if the change is to a specific value.

So far I got this:

```
function sendNotification(e)
{
// static values  
var sheetNameToWatch = "Category";
var orderStatusColToWatch = 13;
var processingStatusColToWatch = 52;
var valueToWatch1 = "In Game";
var columnOfEditedOrder = 3;

//dynamic values  
var ss = e.source;
var range = e.range;
var sheet = e.range.getSheet(); //works
var sheetName = sheet.getName(); //works
var rowOfEditedOrder = range.getRow(); //works
var nameOfEditedItem = getRange(rowOfEditedCard,3).getValue();
  Logger.log(nameOfEditedCard);

if (sheetName == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == 
processingStatusColToWatch)
{
   if (value == valueToWatch1)
   {
    MailApp.sendEmail("everyday@normalemail.com", "Example topic", "Value for item "+nameOfEditedItem+" has been updated to "+valueToWatch1+".");
   }
}
else Logger.log("Something went wrong");
}
```

Now, the issue I have is that the variable nameOfEditedItem is not set properly to the right value, even though rowOfEditedOrder returns correct value. Whenever I use the logger to log the nameOfEditedItem value for me, the logger does not return anything.

I would appreciate the help with this one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bad line

```
var nameOfEditedItem = getRange(rowOfEditedCard,3).getValue();
```

You forgot the sheet object, so you do not have a range to work with and thus you do not have a value. You probably meant to have

```
var nameOfEditedItem = sheet.getRange(rowOfEditedCard,3).getValue();
```

Comment: @AdrianJakubiak consider marking the answer as the correct one :)